# Show:$ 0<L(g,P)\le U(g,P)<1$

Tags: calculus

Let $g$ be an increasing continuous function on $[0,1]$, and suppose

$g(0)=0$

$g(1)=1$.

Show that there is a partition $P$ on $[0,1]$ such that the following inequality applly to the lower and upper riemann sum:

$$0< L(g,P)\le U(g,P)<1$$

Any tips/solutions on how I can go about showing this? (I see how the inequality is true for every partition isnt it? (unless you only have 1 interval in which case $L=0$, and $U=1$ so that doesnt work I guess?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $g$ is increasing $g(x)≥0 \forall x \in [0,1]$ which gives $L(g,P)≥0$ for all partitions $P$. To see that the inequality can be made strict use the continuity at $x=1$ and the fact that $g(1)=1>0$ to chose a suitable partition (find a $\delta$ for which $1-\delta<x<1 $ implies $g(x)>1/2$.

Since $g$ is increasing: $\sup \left \{ g(x) : x\in [0,1] \right \}=g(1)=1$

Hence $U(g,P)≤1$ for all $P$. To see that the inequality can be made strict, use the continuity at $x=0$ and the fact that $g(0)=0$ to find a suitable partition.

Combine both results by passing to refinements (consider the union of both partitions).

Comment: Since $g$ is continuous at $1$ and $g(1)=1$ there exist $\delta >0$ such that $1-\delta <x<1$ implies $|1-g(x)|<1/2$, in particular $g(x)>1/2$. Consider a partition $P=\left \{ 0,x_1,...,1-\delta /2, 1 \right \}$. Note that $\inf g>0$ in $[1-\delta /2,1]$ and hence $L(g,P)>0$.

Comment: $1-\delta <x<1$ implies $|1-g(x)|<1/2$ is just the definition of continuity, where $\varepsilon =1/2$. Since $g$ is continuous we know that there exists such a $\delta$, by definition. "Opening up" the modulus we get: $-1/2<1-g(x)<1/2$. Looking at the last inequality we get $1-1/2<g(x)$. 
As you've correctly identified, your inequality is true for every partition. The hard part of the problem is showing that $0<L(g,P)$ and $U(g,P)<1$ for some $P$. It is here that the continuity is needed. Does this help?

Comment: I'll do it for $L(g,P)>0$ since I've got it written down, showing $U(g,P)<1$ is exactly the same: if $P=\left \{ 0=x_0,x_1,...,x_{n-1}=1-\delta /2, x_n=1 \right \}$ we have (letting $m_i=\inf_{x_{i-1}≤x≤x_i}g(x))$: $L(g,P)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i(x_i-x_{i-1})=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}m_i(x_i-x_{i-1})+m_n(1-(1-\delta))>|sum_{i=1}^{n-1}m_i(x_i-x_{i-1})+1/2\delta≥{1 \over 2}\delta>0$